# What rule prevents entering a user namespace from inside a chroot?

Tags: security, chroot, namespace

```
# rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/unshare
util-linux-2.32-2.fc28.x86_64
# unshare -r
#
```

i.e. the above succeeds, where the following does not.  What rule causes this?

```
# rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/sbin/chroot
coreutils-8.29-6.fc28.x86_64
# chroot fedora-27
# rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/unshare
util-linux-2.30.2-1.fc27.x86_64
# strace unshare -r
...
unshare(CLONE_NEWUSER)      = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://serverfault.com/a/648637/133475

> It's well-known that processes that are capable of using `chroot`, are
>   capable of breaking out of a `chroot`. Since `unshare -r` would grant
>   `chroot` permissions to an ordinary user, it would be a security risk
>   if that was allowed inside a `chroot` environment. Indeed, it is not
>   allowed, and fails with:
>
> > unshare: unshare failed: Operation not permitted
>
> which matches the
>   [unshare(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html)
>   documentation:
>
> > **EPERM** (since Linux 3.9)
> >
> > **CLONE_NEWUSER** was specified in *flags* and the caller is in a chroot environment (i.e., the caller's root directory does not match
> >     the root directory of the mount namespace in which it resides).